# How can I retrieve the internal transaction of transfer ether by contract invoke?

Tags: internal-transactions

I want to retrieve the internal transactions of specified tx, the result should be same as "https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal" api request reuslt.

So I want to know how to do it. There are anyone can give me some example golang code? Thanks very much.

Comment: if go-ethereum doesn't provide a public method, you can make a raw RPC call over HTTP